# $\arcsin(\sin x)$ explanation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

First off, I know this is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148679/why-arent-the-graphs-of-sin-arcsin-x-and-arcsin-sin-x-the-same). I'm asking this because I still don't quite understand the answer given there. But first, some graphs!

- $y=\sin(x)$

  [image: y=sin x]
- $y=\arcsin(x)$

  [image: y=arcsin x]
- $y=\sin(\arcsin(x))$

  [image: y=sin(arcsin x)]
- $y=\arcsin(\sin (x))$

  [image: y=arcsin(sin x)]

What I don't understand is why $f(x) = \arcsin(\sin(x))$ looks like it does. As stated in the previously linked question, $f(x)=\arcsin(x)$ is only defined between $[-1,1]$. So, how does it effect the rest of the graph? Shouldn't the domain be only values of $\sin x$ within the domain of $\arcsin x$?

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: [Why does $\sin^{-1}(\sin(\pi))$ not equal $\pi$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/677432/25554)

Comment: Yes, arcsin is only defined for values in [-1,1] (complex numbers notwithstanding). And sin only takes values in [-1,1]. So therefore any x value can be plugged into arcsin(sin x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\pi\ge x\ge \frac{1}{2}\pi$, we have $\sin[x]=\sin[\pi-x]$. Therefore we have
$$
\arcsin(\sin[x])=\arcsin(\sin[\pi-x])=\pi-x
$$
Similarly for $-\pi\le x\le -\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $\sin[x]=\sin[-\pi-x]$. Therefore we have
$$
\arcsin(\sin[x])=\arcsin(\sin[-\pi-x])=\arcsin(-\sin[\pi+x])=-\arcsin(\sin(\pi+x))=-\pi-x
$$

I think the rest of the graph follows by the same argument. I attached a graph, I do not know if it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Since $\sin(x)$ is always in the interval $[-1,1]$ where $\arcsin$ is defined, 
$\arcsin(\sin(x))$ is defined for all real $x$.

$\arcsin(y)$ is defined as the number $x$ within the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ where $\sin(x) = y$.  So for $x$ in the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, 
$\arcsin(\sin(x)) = x$ satisfies that definition.  For $x$ in the interval $[\pi/2, 3 \pi/2]$, $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ can't be $x$, but it can be $\pi - x$ which is in the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ (notice that $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin(x)$).  So that takes care of this part of the graph:

[image]

Now notice that $\sin(x)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, so  the graph
looks the same if you shift it left or right by $2\pi$.  That takes care of the rest of it.

Comment: So I understand the jist of it; but, I don't get why $sin(π−x)=sin(x)$. Did you mean that this only works for the interval $[−π/2,π/2]$?

Comment: To understand why sin(π−x)=sin(x), we need to start from the extended definition of sine for angles greater than π/2. sin(x) is defined as y-ordinate to the radius of the circle in question. That circle is centered at O(0, 0) and radius = $sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$.

Answer (score 4):

So let $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and let $g(x)=\arcsin(x)$. Let $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$ be the domain of $f$ and let $\operatorname{Rng}(f)$ be the range of $f$. Thus we have
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Dom}(f)&=\mathbb{R}\\ 
\operatorname{Rng}(f)&=[-1,1]\\
\operatorname{Dom}(g)&=[-1,1]\\ 
\operatorname{Rng}(g)&=\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]
\end{align}
$$

If we restrict the $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$ to $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, then $f$ and $g$ are inverses of one another and

$$
(f\circ g)(x)=(g\circ f)(x) = x
$$

on $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Now let $\operatorname{Dom}(f)=\mathbb{R}$ and consider $(f\circ g)(x)$. This graph should remain unchanged since for any $x\not\in[-1,1]$, $(f\circ g)(x)$ is not defined and so no picture can be drawn on $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]$.

On the other hand, when we let $\operatorname{Dom}(f)=\mathbb{R}$ and consider $(g\circ f)(x)$, this composition is defined over all of $\mathbb{R}$, but it behaves in two different ways:

1.) On the intervals $\left[\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2},\frac{\pi\cdot(2k+1)}{2}\right]$ when $k$ is odd: As $x$ goes from $\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi(2k+1)}{2}$, $f(x)$ goes from $-1$ to $1$. Thus $(g\circ f)$ goes from $\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi(2k+1)}{2}$, forming a positively sloped line.

2.) On the intervals $\left[\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2},\frac{\pi\cdot(2k+1)}{2}\right]$ when $k$ is even: As $x$ goes from $\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi(2k+1)}{2}$, $f(x)$ goes from $1$ to $-1$. Thus $(g\circ f)$ goes from $\frac{\pi(2k+1)}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2}$, forming a negatively sloped line.

This is why you see the jigsaw pattern when you graph $(g\circ f)$  and don't see any change in $(f\circ g)$.

Comment: Great. But where do the$/frac{[π(2k−1)}{2}$ and $/frac{π⋅(2k+1)}{2}]$ come from? Specifically the $2k-1$ and $2k+1$ parts in the numberators.

Comment: It is just a way to index the domain in chunks where the function behaves the same way. We are just a shifting the original domain $[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. The first few values of $k=-2,-1,0,1,2$ give $[\frac{-5\pi}{2},\frac{-3\pi}{2}]$, $[\frac{-3\pi}{2},\frac{-\pi}{2}]$, $[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$, $[\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2}]$ etc...

Comment: @LaarsHelenius How do we know that $g\circ f$ goes from $\pi(2k+1)/2$ to $\pi(2k-1)/2$ in a linear fashion?