# Is $\sqrt{x^2} = x$?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

Does the $\sqrt{x^2}$ always equal $x$? I am trying to prove that $i^2 = -1$, but to do that I need to know that $\sqrt{(-1)^2} = -1$. If that is true then all real numbers are imaginary, because an imaginary number is any number that can be written in terms of $i$. For example, 2 can be written as $i^2 + 3$. Does this work or did I make an error?

Comment: $i^2+3$ not 2i+3

Comment: Imaginary numbers are of the form $ib$ where $b$ is real. It is not right to say that 'in terms of $i$'.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta, it's not an imaginary number since $i^2 + 3 = -1 + 3 = 2$ so it's in the form $a$. Mostly because $a,b$ in $a+bi$ are restricted to real numbers

Comment: ${\sqrt x}^2$ always equals $x$. $\sqrt{x^2}$ equals $\lvert x\rvert$ for real values of $x$. (By the way: $2=i^2+3$, yes.)

Comment: I think you are talking about complex numbers, $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ in the same way that $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is square root the inverse of the square?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154317/when-is-square-root-the-inverse-of-the-square)

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to *prove* that $i^2 = -1$, since it's true by definition. I can't think of a case when you can prove that a definition is true; it's defined to be so.

Answer (score 2):

Not always. $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt{1}=1\neq -1$. In general $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$

Comment: Equation $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ is only for real $x$.

Comment: In general $\sqrt{x^2}=\pm x$.

Comment: @Meelo, the symbol $\sqrt{}$ by definition denotes the nonnegative square root.

Comment: @SantigoCanez Oh, I was intending my equation to be read as "$\sqrt{x^2}$ is either $x$ or $-x$" not "$\sqrt{x^2}$ is both $x$ and $-x$." This might have been unclear. (I used $\pm$ instead of $|\cdot |$ to emphasize that, for complex input, the principal value can't be taken to be the non-negative square root since no such thing exists)

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not true that $\sqrt{x^2} = x$.  As a very simple example, with $x=-2$, we obtain
   $$ \sqrt{(-2)^2} = \sqrt{4} = 2 \ne -2. $$
   In general, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.  Things get more complicated when you start working with complex numbers, but I think that a discussion of "branches of the square root function" is quite a bit beyond the scope of this question.
2. There is a serious problem of definitions in the question.  The question asserts "...all real numbers are imaginary, because an imaginary number is any number that can be written in terms of $i$."  However, this is not the definition of an imaginary number.  An imaginary number is a number $z$ such that there is some real number $y$ such that $z = iy$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit.  A number such as $i^2 + 3$ is *not* an imaginary number, since there is no real number $y$ such that $2 = i^2 + 3 = iy$.

   On the other hand, it is reasonable to say that every real number is a *complex number*.  A complex number is a number $z$ such that there are $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $z = x + iy$.  In the case of the example give, we have
   $$ i^2 + 3 = (-1) + 3 = 2 = 2 + i0. $$